# Receiver messages are displaying twice in XMPP chat in IOS app

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am using xmpp chat framework in my app. In group chat, I enter to a chat room and send message. Other user will also send a message in same chat room. When I go to an another chat room and then visit the previous chat room. The messages send by the other user is displayed twice. It happens as many times when I enter it. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Post your code to get actual cause of problem, there are many possible answers.

Comment: I'm storing the message when a message is received through  didReceiveMessage delegate into a database . When I enter the same chat room again didReceiveMessage delegate is called for all messages including previous message and all the message and again got added to Database.

Comment: Prevent duplicate message using MessageId. Check if a message with same id exist then don't insert.

Comment: It helps me a lot. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted any code. However just check while exiting/switching MUC are you properly exiting the MUC or not? Try once exiting the room properly as below code:

```
[theRoom deactivate];
[theRoom removeDelegate:self];
theRoom = nil;
```